# How to use the parent class view in STI rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, view, sti

I have a Class Meeting from which derives MeetingOnline and MeetingOnSite.

I want to be able to use the views of Meeting for both MeetingOnline and MeetingOnSite.

Now when i do `<%= render @meetings %>` it asks me for `meeting_on_lines/_meeting_on_line_partial`. But i want him to use instead meetings/_meeting since what i want to show is shared between the 2 derived models.

In my controller i have `@meetings = Meeting.all` simply.

Any clues on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly set the partial.  By jsut using `render @meetings` rails is making an assumption about which partial to use

```
<%= render partial: "meetings/meeting", collection: @meetings %>
```